# iOS 9.3 iBooks for iPhone starts with a blank shelf screen

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, books

I noticed that since updating to iBooks using iCloud with iOS 9.3, I'm starting to see this "blank screen" page when staring iBooks. The books are still there, searchable by name or visible when tapping the top left icon.

Toggling between list/shelf view makes books visible on the shelf view again, but this is rather annoying.

**How can I make sure my iBooks works properly with iOS 9.3 and iCloud?**

[image]

Comment: I don't have that problem.  I'm on 9.3 and use iCloud with iBooks and when I start iBooks I see all my books.  However, I don't have the cloud with the arrow icon on the top-right like your do in the screenshot.

Comment: Yeah, I never had problems with iBooks before, maybe it has something to do with the upgrade process? The books are there, it's just the display that is screwed up.

Comment: Is it possible to delete ibooks and reinstall it?  I've never tried that.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and changed the setting on the top of the screen from "All books" to just "Audiobooks" (because I just use it for audiobooks)
Should also work if you switch to just "pdf" or just "Books".
Give it a try. it solved my problem and no blank screen anymore when you open Ibooks